# Error: Main method not found in class, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, runtime-error, applet

I tried running this java code, and it came up with the following error:

```
Main method not found in class p16, please define the main method as:
    public static void main(String[] args)
    or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

My Code:

```
//button events
//on pressing a button color changes
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
 <applet code = p16 width= 140 height=140>
 </applet>
 */
public class p16 extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    String msg = "";
    Button first, second;

    public void init() {
        first = new Button("yes");
        second = new Button("no");
        add(first);
        add(second);
        first.addActionListener(this);
        second.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String str = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (str.equals("yes")) {
            first.setBackground(Color.red);
            second.setBackground(Color.white);
            msg = "pressed yes";
        } else {
            second.setBackground(Color.blue);
            first.setBackground(Color.white);
            msg = "pressed no";
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(msg, 13, 12);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to format your code - it's *really* hard to read like that. Next, you've declared an applet, which is effectively a legacy type of application. You don't just run applets in the same way, and I'd advise you to move to a different kind of application entirely.

Comment: That is an Applet. Applet are a.) ancient, b.) unsupported and c.) not launched via the `java` executable. If you just found a course that tries to teach you Java: run away and find another one, because that one is outdated. If you actually want to develop an Applet: don't, that's ancient tech and should be left alone. if you want to do something a little like an applet, write a normal Java application using Swing. It will run standalone and not in a browser, but Java in the browser is dead anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Applet cannot be run from command line like common Java applications.
You need to add applet to a webpage, read online about that.

Comment: Or even better: give up on using Applets. Support was deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11.

Comment: *"Applet cannot be run from command line .."* Yes they could. The HTML embedded in a comment at the top of the source code file was interpreted to be HTML for the Applet Viewer. This ability was introduced in about Java 1.4 / 1.5. Of course since then, applets were deprecated and removed from the API, so adding it to a web page won't work these days. Most browser manufacturers had removed the ability to embed plug-ins even before Java removed them from the API. So your answer is more wrong, than right.

Answer (score 0):

With a little effort, you can turn your applet into an application. You can then continue working there.

Here are the changes:

```
//button events
//on pressing a button color changes
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// Change the class name so that it complies with Java naming conventions.
// Extend a JPanel instead of an Applet
public class P16 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    String msg = "";
    Button first;
    Button second;

    // Add a main() method that creates a JFrame
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        // Set a new Instance of your Class as ContentPane
        frame.setContentPane(new P16());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);        
    }

    // Make your class constructor out of the Init () method
    public P16() {
        first = new Button("yes");
        second = new Button("no");
        add(first);
        add(second);
        first.addActionListener(this);
        second.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String str = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (str.equals("yes")) {
            first.setBackground(Color.red);
            second.setBackground(Color.white);
            msg = "pressed yes";
        } else {
            second.setBackground(Color.blue);
            first.setBackground(Color.white);
            msg = "pressed no";
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(msg, 13, 12);
    }
}
```

Maybe that's a help.

Answer (score 0):

On Netbeans IDE: You can right click the class from application folder and choose **run file** ,But it will give you same error if you pressed run button from toolbars

On Eclipce : it runs either ways

- run button from toolbars
- right click the class from application folder and run as java applet

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

1. Install NetBeans IDE 8.2
2. Click on New File
3. Choose categories: Java, File Types: Applet
4. Give Class Name for your Applet
5. Write your code
6. In project section of IDE select your Applet, right click and choose Run File